# How is the BarSpacing option really implemented in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, plot, bar-chart

I'm trying to implement a `DateListBarChart` function that takes dated data and outputs a bar chart with the same placements as `DateListPlot`. It's essential that they plot data in the same horizontal position if given the same data, so they can be combined using `Show`. I am finding it difficult to get the settings for `BarSpacing` right so that the horizontal range of the plot doesn't change, and the bars stay in essentially the same place.

I have been unable to infer the correct scaling so that `BarSpacing->{0.2,0.3}` results in 20% of the x-axis length available for that group of bars is taken up with spacing between bars in that group, and 30% as spacing between groups of bars. For technical reasons I am doing this by passing things to `RectangleChart`. According to the documentation, `BarSpacing` is treated as absolute units in `RectangleChart`. Obviously the absolute sizes of the gaps need to be smaller if there are more series, and the bars need to be narrower.

Some examples:

```
arList = FoldList[0.9 #1 + #2 &, 0.01, RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 24]]

{0.01, 0.334557, 2.02709, 1.1878, 1.9009, 3.08604, 2.36652, 3.04111, 
3.32364, 3.22662, 3.12626, 2.59118, 1.69334, 1.21069, 0.23171, 
0.689415, -0.852649, -0.124624, 0.58604, -0.481886, 0.221074, 
-0.300329, 2.36137, 0.427789, -1.47747}

dists = RandomChoice[{3, 4}, Length[arList]]
{4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3}
```

Results in:

```
RectangleChart[Transpose[{dists - 0 - 0/2, arList}], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {-2, 4}}, ChartStyle -> EdgeForm[None], 
 Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, BarSpacing -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

```
RectangleChart[Transpose[{dists - 0.7 - 0.5/2, arList}], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {-2, 4}}, ChartStyle -> EdgeForm[None], 
 Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, BarSpacing -> {0.7, 0.5}]
```

[image]

Notice how the data aren't spanning the same distance along the x-axis as the previous example.

It gets even messier when trying to chart multiple series (the same in this example, for illustration).

```
RectangleChart[
 Transpose[{{dists - i/2 - j/2, arList}, {dists - i/2 - j/2, 
  arList}}, {2, 3, 1}], PlotRange -> {{0, 180}, {-2, 4}}, 
 ChartStyle -> EdgeForm[None], Frame -> True, Ticks -> None, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, BarSpacing -> {i, j}]
```

[image]

I've been futzing for ages trying to find the right formula so that `BarSpacing` settings for the custom function (not seen here) induce the correct spacings and bar widths so that the horizontal plot range doesn't change as the `BarSpacing` does.

What am I missing?

EDIT: In response to belisarius, this is an example of where I am heading. It works, kind of (the bars aren't quite in alignment with the line, but this is probably the dates I am using) but the cases with stacked bars fail to plot with the bars where they should be, as do any kind of bar graph on its own where there are multiple series. (I'm quite proud of the date label placement algorithm:  the powers that be at work don't want to give up that look.)

[image]

And here is one that just isn't working. The data should fill the horizontal range. (The different width bars are deliberate - it's a combination of annual and quarterly data.)

[image]

**EDIT 2**

I remember why I didn't use `Filling` in a `DateListPlot` to draw the bars as in Mike Honeychurch's package - if you have anything other than very skinny bars, they end up having the top edge in the wrong place.

```
DateListPlot[{dateARList}, 
 PlotStyle -> {AbsolutePointSize[6], Yellow}, Filling -> {1 -> 0}, 
 FillingStyle -> {1 -> {{AbsoluteThickness[12], Darker[Red, 0.25]}}}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: I think Mike Honeychurch's `VolumePlot` function may prove useful. You can find the code here: http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/7526/ As far as I can tell, this code seems to be a preliminary version of the new finance visualization plots in v8. Helpful?

Comment: _Perhaps_ an example (picture) of what you are trying to do with `DateListPlot` (although failed) could help me understand the problem ...

Comment: @belisarius - see if this helps. The organisational graph style is very particular.

Comment: @Verbia, I've had a very similar issue once, using Mathematica 7. The way I solved it was implementing own bar-chart behaviour as needed using the Rectangle[] graphics primitives. There's way too much magic going on with BarChart and related plots, and I ended up giving up on it. After half a days work, I had my solution in a 100-line long function.

Comment: @Gleno, that's exactly what I am doing, customising `RectangleChart`. It's more like 30 lines of code than 100, but I still can't get the right formula for spacing the bars correctly relative to the ticks.

Comment: @telefunkenvf14 - see my edit - Mike's solution only works for skinny bars, and won't work at all for irregular-shaped data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe using the [`ChartElementFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ChartElementFunction.html) option instead of [`BarSpacing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BarSpacing.html) helps. For example `barplot` in the code would plot a bar chart such that each bar has margins of `gapl` on the left and `gapr` on the right where `gapl` and `gapr` are fractions of the total width of the bar

```
scale[{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}, {gapl_, gapr_}] :=
 {{xmin (1 - gapl) + xmax gapl, ymin}, {xmax (1 - gapr) + xmin gapr, ymax}}

barplot[dists_, arList_, {gapl_, gapr_}, opts___] := 
 RectangleChart[Transpose[{dists, arList }], opts, 
  Frame -> True, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, BarSpacing -> 0,
  ChartElementFunction -> (Rectangle @@ scale[#, {gapl, gapr}] &)]
```

**Usage:**

To plot the original bar chart with no gaps

```
barplot[dists, arList, {0, 0}]
```

[image: rectangle chart with no gaps]

This would plot a bar chart with a margin of 0.2 on both sides which results in a bar chart  with gaps of 0.4 times the total width of the bars. Note that the positions of the bars matches with those in the first figure.

```
barplot[dists, arList, {0.2, 0.2}]
```

[image: barchart with gaps]

You can plot multiple series by doing something like

```
Show[barplot[dists, arList 0.9, {0, 0.5}],
 barplot[dists, arList 0.8, {0.5, 0}, ChartStyle -> LightGreen]]
```

[image: two series in one plot]

Comment: +1 That's awesome, Heike - I never thought of `ChartElementFunction`.

Comment: I just confirmed that it works. It turns out that if you scale the widths of the rectangles for the number of series (which I was doing anyway) you don't even need to use `Show`. I pick up the value of the `BarSpacing` option and then use `ChartElementFunction -> (Rectangle @@ barscale[#, {gapfactorwithin/(2 xscaling), gapfactorwithin/(2 xscaling)}] &)`, while setting `BarSpacing` back to 0 in the actual `RectangleChart`. Thanks again Heike, that has helped me so much. This is another example when I should stop banging my head against the keyboard and ask the internet sooner :)

Comment: It's a pity we can't weight our votes according to how much time someone has saved us :)

Comment: @Verbeia [`Bounties`](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) are intended to reward that

Comment: ok, so I looked up the FAQ and I have to wait until tomorrow to set that.

Comment: I have started a bounty worth the exact difference between my reputation and @Heike 's at the time I started it. I have to wait till tomorrow until I award it.

Comment: @Verbeia, great sportsmanship regarding the retroactive bounty.  Heike, this is a fine solution.

Answer (score 5):

You may relieve your complaint about `FillingStyle` by using `CapForm["Butt"]`.

```
list = {0.01, -0.81, 0.12, 0.81, 1.79, 1.1, 0.41, 1., 1.33, 1.08, 
  2.16, 1.13, 1.92, 1.64, 1.31, 1.94, 1.71, 0.91, 2.32, 0.95, 1.29, 
  1.28, 2.97, 4.45, 5.11}

DateListPlot[list, {2000, 8}, 
 PlotStyle -> {AbsolutePointSize[6], Yellow}, Filling -> {1 -> 0}, 
 FillingStyle -> {1 -> {{CapForm["Butt"], AbsoluteThickness[14], 
      Darker[Red, 0.25]}}}, PlotRange -> {0, 6}, ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

Comment: that is an awesome solution! It isn't suitable for stacked bars and multiple series, unless I do some manipulation of data sets to be cumulative. But it might be a useful option for single line-bar and bar charts given this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396898/why-do-barchart-graphics-exported-from-mathematica-have-pixelated-text-is-there

Comment: @Verbeia, I know it's not a complete solution, but I thought it would be helpful, and it is very simple.

Comment: it is, and the use of `CapForm` in a Style option is not well known. That +1 was me.