# Can we decrease Bar size width in BarChart in Mathematica?

Tags: formatting, wolfram-mathematica, bar-chart

```
dalist = {901, 503, 522, 1305} 

cogColors = {RGBColor[0, 0, 1], RGBColor[1, 0, 0], RGBColor[0, 1, 0], RGBColor[1, 1, 0]}

BarChart[dalist, ChartStyle -> cogColors]
```

[image]

Is it possible to decrease the Bars Width ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BarChart is not intended to do that. You can only change the spacings.

Use RectangleChart instead if you need finer control:

```
RectangleChart[{{{1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{2, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 2}}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I may be missing the point, but cannot you merely change the aspect ratio?

```
BarChart[dalist, ChartStyle -> cogColors, AspectRatio -> 3, ImageSize -> 120]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Rather than changing the bar chart width, you can increase the bar spacing.

```
BarChart[dalist, ChartStyle -> cogColors, BarSpacing -> 1]
```

[image: Bar chart with greater spacing]

Answer (score 2):

See Heike's answer to my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293317/how-is-the-barspacing-option-really-implemented-in-mathematica). You need to use `RectangleChart`. If you want to keep a constant distance between bar centres, so that the bar-plus-spacing takes up a constant space, you can use the `ChartElementFunction` option together with an auxiliary function, as shown in Heike's answer. (This might also do what you want using `BarChart`, but I'd still recommend `RectangleChart`.)

Comment: upvoters, please upvote Heike's answer on the other question, too, if you haven't already